# Não consigo capturar a mensagem que mando na minha Exception Personalizada Java

Tags: java

Galera, boa tarde!

Preciso de um help, estou criando algumas apis em java e criei algumas exceptions personalisadas, quando invoco a exeção tipo que criei:
throw new RecursoNaoEncontradoException(“Recurso não encontrado”); ,
Obtenho de retorno no Json, sem o campo message preenchido :
{
“timestamp”: “2020-12-10T17:04:44.123+00:00”,
“status”: 404,
“error”: “Not Found”,
“message”: “”,
“path”: “/mkpnumapi/v1/if/1111”
}

alguem sabe dizer o pq não está capturando a mensagem que envio ?

Minha Classe que criei a Exception Exntendo de RuntiMeException

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class RecursoNaoEncontradoException extends RuntimeException {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public RecursoNaoEncontradoException(String message) {
        super(message);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    
}


Chamadando a Exception na minha controller

@ApiOperation(value = "Metodo - deletarOfertante", nickname = "deletarOfertante")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK - Request Aceito"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request - Request ou Parametros Incorretos") })
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/ofertante/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletarOfertante(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        Integer result = service.buscarOfertantePorId(id);
        if (result == 0) {
            throw new RecursoNaoEncontradoException("Recurso inexistente");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.excluirOfertante(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Retorno Response:

{
"timestamp": "2020-12-10T17:04:44.123+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/mkpnumapi/v1/if/1111"
}

Comment: Sem o código não tem como adivinhar.

Comment: Opa Adriano, adicionei o code.

Comment: @AdrianoSiqueira adicionei o code.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, sua classe precisa coincidir com os construtores da super classe de Exception, veja o [exemplo aqui](https://github.com/AdrianoSiqueira/ASLib/blob/master/src/aslib/exceptions/ExecutionNotDoneException.java).

Depois, na classe onde deseja pegar a mensagem, você faz assim:

```
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            // Qualquer coisa
            throw new MinhaExcecaoException("Mensagem personalizada.");
        } catch (MinhaExcecaoException e) {
            System.out.println("Mensagem: " + e.getMessage());
          
            /*
             * Isso vai printar:
             *
             * Mensagem: Mensagem personalizada.
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

segue um exemplo da forma que pode utilizar,

Primeiramente crie uma classe de exception no estilo:

```
public class RecursoNaoEncontradoException extends RuntimeException {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public RecursoNaoEncontradoException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Posteriormente crie um handler para capturar a mensagem de exception que você jogou e realizar alguma ação:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RecursoNaoEncontradoHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(RecursoNaoEncontradoException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> RecursoNaoEncontradoException(RecursoNaoEncontradoException ex) {
        
        HashMap<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();
        
        message.put("Message:", ex.getMessage());
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .body(message);
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.